# References on Weak Convervenge

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I am looking for a good reference on weak convergence in L^p spaces, can anyone recommend anything?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/epsilon.pdf Tao's Epsilon of Room, Vol. I has some on that.